# PHP Loop through months, starting in December

Tags: php, mysql, date, loops, if-statement

I need to loop through the months of the year between December 2012 to November 2017. So starting month is 12, ending month is 11, starting year is 2012, ending year is 2017.

Then I'm querying a database with date format as 2014-03-27 00:00:00

I know I've done this sort of thing about 4 years ago but cannot seem to be able to nut it out now.
Here's what I have:

```
$year_start = 2012;
$year_end = 2017;
$month_start = 12;
$month_end = 11;

$year = $year_start;
$month = $month_start;

$number_of_months = 3;

if ($month < 13 && $year < $year_end ) {

    $between_year_month = $year.'-'.$month;
    //echo $between_year_month;

    $query_total = "SELECT SUM(sales_points) FROM sales_list 
                    WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['users_id']."' 
                    AND sales_date BETWEEN '".$between_year_month."-01 00:00:00' AND '".$between_year_month."-30 23:59:59'";

    echo $query_total;

    $month++;

    if($month == 13) {
            $month = 1;
            $year = $year + 1;
    }

    $between_year_month = $year.'-'.$month;
    //echo $between_year_month;
```

}

Your help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I posted n answer and then realized I don't know what problem you are actually having.

Comment: Loop and do what? Anyway you can trunc the date in the database down to the year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your biggest issue is you never actually executed your query. I also simplified your loop by using [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [`DateInterval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), and [`DatePeriod()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php).

```
$start    = new DateTime('2012-12-01');
$end      = new DateTime('2017-11-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) { 
    $first_of_month = $dt->modify('first day of this month')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $end_of_month   = $dt->modify('last day of this month')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $query_total = "SELECT SUM(sales_points) FROM sales_list 
                WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['users_id']."' 
                AND sales_date BETWEEN '".$first_of_month ."' 
                AND '".$end_of_month   ."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($query_total, $conn);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, your solution is exactly what I was after. Loop through dates with start and end limits. I left the database mysql_query off as it was ultimately irrelevant to the problem of just looping through the dates. Fantastic.